# How to discriminate safe area between left and right side?

Tags: swift, uikit, safearea

Though it is easy to handle safe area with constraints, I am looking for something to differentiate between left and right side in landscape mode depending on where actually stands the notch.

As you know it, standard safe area handling leads to a symmetric treatment as follows:

[image]

I want to use the opposite side (right side in the photo) for my views.

Comment: Are you saying that the safe area on the right is unnecessary because there is nothing there, and you want your views to be extended all the way to the edge?

Comment: Exactly. And if the user rotates the iPhone in such a way the notch now stands on the right, I then want to use the left side.

Comment: Apple does not support this sort of asymmetrical design. You can hack around this by checking the interface orientation directly and changing the safe area constraints to margin constraints. But I recommend not supporting landscape mode if you think this doesn't look good, or embracing this design! Look at WhatsApp for example. See also this [related complaint](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/92407).